# How to properly handle hazelcast write behind infinite retries

Tags: caching, error-handling, hazelcast

I am using a write behind mapstore in my cache and I noticed that if the db call fails the thread will retry 3 times then print stacktrace and then repeat indefinitely.

Is there anyway we can handle this properly? or at least some way to inject some code so the admins are notified? Right now I didn't know about it until I open up my log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, current behavior is retrying failed entries. There are plans already in place to add a retry limit for Mapstore operations in the upcoming versions.

As a workaround you can catch the specific exception thrown in your MapStore implementation so those objects are skipped.

Comment: ok guess I will write an interceptor for now.  I hope the new feature will allow us to inject our own code in when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by handling properly but you can certainly catch exception in your code and take whatever actions you like.